# androidx.navigation.NavGraph cannot be cast to androidx.navigation.compose.ComposeNavigator$Destination

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

After updating navigation compose dependency from **2.4.0-alpha03** to **2.4.0-alpha05** I've encountered this strange error after trying to navigate between composable screens (For example navigate from taskComposable to listComposable screen). Here's a part of my code.

**MainActivity:**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController

    @ExperimentalAnimationApi
    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyComposeDemoTheme {
                navController = rememberNavController()
                SetupNavigation(
                    navController = navController
                )
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**SetupNavigation:**

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun SetupNavigation(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    val screen = remember(navController) { Screens(navController) }

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "list/{action}"
    ) {
        listComposable(
            navigateToTaskScreen = screen.task
        )
        taskComposable(
            navigateToListScreen = screen.list
        )
    }
}
```

**Screens:**

```
class Screens(navController: NavHostController) {
    val list: (Action) -> Unit = { action ->
        navController.navigate("list/${action.name}"){
            popUpTo(LIST_SCREEN) { inclusive = true }
        }
    }
    val task: (Int) -> Unit = { taskId ->
        navController.navigate("task/$taskId")
    }
}
```

**taskComposable**

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.taskComposable(
    navigateToListScreen: (Action) -> Unit
) {
    composable(
        route = TASK_SCREEN,
        arguments = listOf(navArgument(TASK_ID_ARGUMENT_KEY) {
            type = NavType.IntType
        })
    ) {
        TaskScreen(
            navigateToListScreen = navigateToListScreen
        )
    }
}
```

Error:

> Process: com.example.mycomposedemo, PID: 2413
> java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.navigation.NavGraph cannot be cast to androidx.navigation.compose.ComposeNavigator$Destination
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$6$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:146)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$6$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:145)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:59)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:50)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:46)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$6.invoke(NavHost.kt:145)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$6.invoke(NavHost.kt:144)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$1$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:74)
> at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$1$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:69)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:86)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:144)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$7.invoke(Unknown
> Source:13)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$7.invoke(Unknown
> Source:10)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:140)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2156)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2399)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2580)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2573)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotState.kt:540)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2566)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2542)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:613)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:764)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:103)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:447)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:416)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
> 2021-07-29 10:00:14.416 2413-2413/com.example.mycomposedemo
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:964)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:721)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Comment: I'm also getting it and there's a ticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194301889

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an internal bug which will be fixed in Navigation 2.4.0-alpha06 release. @headsvk shared the issue link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194301889